# spare blanks with php

Tags: php, character

I have the following line in a php file:

```
$labels['study'] = 'Study';
```

Then, I include that file in my index page to print the value. It gets the value but instead of printing "Study", it prints " Study" (with a blank at the beginnig).
I've tried aplying trim() to the returned value and in other places but it has no effect.

The way I'm returning the value is:

```
<?=get_label('study')?>
```

There is always a blank (or other blank characters) at the beginning.

I'm wondering why this happens. Any idea?

The get_label function is this:

```
function get_label($texto){
    require("lang/".$_SESSION['lang'].".php");
    $traduccion = trim($labels[$texto]);
    if($traduccion == '')
        return '['.$texto.']';
    else
        return $traduccion;
```

And the code above and below where I call the function:

```
<div>
    <h2><?=get_label('Estudio')?></h2>
    <?=get_text('estudio');?></div> 
</div>
```

I've tried with all of it in the same line (from  to ) and it neither works.

Comment: what's your get_label function?

Comment: You need to show a) what `get_label()` does and b) the code surrounding the function call.

Comment: In the first php file, you likely have a space before the `<?=` tag...like `_<?=... ?>`

Comment: my guess would be that you've got some whitespace prior to the `<?=`, but without seeing more of your code, that really is just a pure guess. The other option is that there's a problem in your `get_label()` function, but again without seeing it, I wouldn't be able to say for sure.

Comment: can you share code at least 2/3 line above the <?=get_label('study')?> and 2/3 line below <?=get_label('study')?> statement ?

Comment: Printing doesn't do this. You have a bug in the function that you didn't show us, or you're interpreting the results incorrectly. There is no testcase provided that can reproduce the issue, and so no question here.

Comment: I've edited the first post with the function's code.

Comment: Oh, I've got it!! I had a few spaces after the php file where all the functions where defined. And when it loaded it, as they where outside a php block, it thought they where blank spaces in html, so it inserted one blank space at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a space in the HTML code before the `<?=` tag, not in the PHP variable.

If that's not a space, it could be a new line as well (in the HTML).

Comment: yeah, this is what I thought aswell, it's happened to me before in a slightly different way.

Comment: Any PHP files which are included in the process of calling that function also need to be checked for whitespace before `<?php` and after `?>`. In fact, if a PHP file contains pure PHP (i.e. not embedded in HTML), the `?>` at the end of the file is optional.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies elsewhere with the whitespace but you could try returning a substring - i.e. everything but the first character (which is the space) or try regexp to get rid of the whitespace?

```
echo substr('abcdef', 1);     // bcdef
```

or

```
$sPattern = '/\s*/m';
$sReplace = '';
$sTestString = $labels['study'] 

preg_replace( $sPattern, $sReplace, $sTestString )
```

Comment: If a `trim` didn't change a thing, and given `$labels['study'] = 'Study';`, it's highly probable that the PHP code is not to blame I'd say

Comment: yeah I agree with you but was just trying to give the OP some other things he might be able to try but now that I think about it these are probably not going to do much good.